# Introductory equivalence relations xRY

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have a question about members/subsets.

> Let A be a nonempty set and let B be a subset of the power set $\mathcal{P} ({A})$ of A. Define a relation R from A to B by xRY if x ∈ Y. Give an example of two sets A and B that illustrate this. What is R for these two sets?

Say we take the set A = {1, 2, 3}. Let B be the subset of its powerset, say B = { {1}, {2}, {1,2} }. Then it seems to me that any element of A, say 1, is not an element of B. For example the element 1 is not a member of B, only the element {1} is. I'm obviously misunderstanding something though, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Example: $R = \{ (1, \{ 1 \} ), (2, \{ 1, 2 \}) \}$.

Comment: But my question still holds? 1 is not an element of the set { {1} }?

Comment: Obviously YES: $1 \in \{ 1 \}$ and $2 \in \{ 1,2 \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That is not what I wrote? Power set elements are sets themselves, so only a set can be its element. I.e. 1 ∈ {1}, but 1 $\not\in$ { {1} }. And for A = {1, 2}, its powerset would be { {1}, {2}, {1, 2}, $\emptyset$} and one of the possible subsets is { {1}, {1,2} }, so the only elements are {1} and {1,2}, not 1 and/or 2.

Comment: The elements of $B$ are indeed subsets of $A$, therefore it makes perfect sense to ask whether $x\in Y$ holds or not for $x\in A$ and $Y\in B$. I can't get your problem. In the particular example you gave we'll have $R=\{(1,\{1\}),\ (1,\{1,2\}),\ (2,\{2\}),\ (2,\{1,2\})\}$.

Comment: @Berci Ok, got it! The problem was that I assumed Y = B, instead of realising that each of the subsets Y are elements of B. Thanks for your time.